# Assigning array exceeds dimension without error message

Tags: arrays, memory, fortran, intel-fortran

I have the following Fortran 90 code. The code assigns value beyond the dimension of an array. ifort compiles it without any error message and I can get the right value.

```
program array_dim

   implicit none

   integer :: matrix(3,3), i , j 



   do i=1,3
      do j = 1, 3
         matrix(i, j) = i+j
      end do
   end do

   matrix(5,5) = 5.0

   write (*,*), 'hello', matrix(5,5)

end program array_dim
```

I think this is unsafe. I somehow remembered that it happened to me once, that an array member exceeds its dimension got a value, then the program gave wrong output value. It seems that this case could affect the memory of other variables.

Is there any way in ifort to provide an error message when exceeds dimension of array? Or other compiler would warn it?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: We recommend here people to use the debugging options very often. Use `-g -warn -traceback -check` for a comprehensive set of options. The specific option is `-check bounds`. I vote to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600844/ifort-and-out-of-bound-index-odd-behaviour instead of writing an answer because the content is essentially the same even if wording is different.

Comment: Yes, the above link answers my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did not find the botton. Am I too late? :(

Comment: Don't worry it was done for you by another user.