# Can overindexing in FORTRAN 77 modify the program itself?

Tags: fortran

Here is a little program in FORTRAN 77

```
      dimension totlev(20)

      do 100 i=1,24
       totlev(i)=0.0
       write(0,*) 'totlev i=',i, totlev(i)
  100 continue

      end
```

I compile it using MinGW by typing gfortran test.f and I do get a warning (not an error):

```
test.f:4:14:

       do 100 i=1,25
                                                                        2
        totlev(i)=0.0
              1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (25 > 20) in loop beginning at (2)

test.f:5:40:

test.f:3:72:

       do 100 i=1,25
                                                                        2
test.f:5:40:

        write(0,*) 'totlev i=',i, totlev(i)
                                        1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (25 > 20) in loop beginning at (2)
```

However, not always such a warning would be produced if it was a longer program. An executable is created. When I run it it behaves like an infinite loop.

[image]

And this is my problem: How is an infinite loop even possible with the DO iteration? Isn't it a logical impossibility? My only explanation is that overindexing in this case reaches to the program code itself and changes it. Is that possible?

I use Windows 7 OS if that's relevant.

Comment: No, in modern operating systems it is not possible. The code segment is read only. And such a simple program does not use executeble stack. Did you **really** read the links sprovided to you in your last question (almost the same)? One of the clearly stresses that *anything* can happen when your program is not standard conforming. The program may start WW3 or summon nasal demons.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785353/why-is-this-fortran-77-program-with-out-of-bound-array-allowed-to-run Please explain why the links do not answer your queation.

Comment: Because by overindexing your arrays you are inadvertently modifying one of the loop control variables, that's all. And it is pretty random, **anything** can happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a Fortran program that should give segmentation fault but it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186674/i-have-a-fortran-program-that-should-give-segmentation-fault-but-it-doesnt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ifort and out of bound Index - Odd Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600844/ifort-and-out-of-bound-index-odd-behaviour)

Comment: Also please don't delete a question which has been closed and then repost one which is essentially the same. Modify the old one to explain why you don't think it is a duplicate, and then it can get reopened

Comment: 1. Please do NOT SCREAM. 2. Be sure we read your question. 3. Questions can be and frequently become reopened. 4. One can get automatically  question-banned also for deleted questions.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: @Makyen You first block my account FOR asking this question on the grounds that it contributes nothing. When I want to delete it you suddenly decide that after all you want to keep it. Why? Make up your mind. Unblock my account if this question has merits. OR delete this question if it's superfluous. I wonder how this inability of logic aids you in your work. You're the one vandalising SE!

Comment: @Peter The system automatically blocked you from asking questions. Moderators have no control over the automatic question and answer bans. We can't impose those bans or lift them. We don't even know what the algorithm is, exactly. We do know some portions of it. For example, deleting an answered question is the *worst* thing you could do from that algorithm's point of view. The best information available as to what you can do in this situation is in '[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/3773011)'

Answer (score 4):

It's not changing the code, it's changing the variable i. Both the array totlev(20) and the scalar i are local variables, and thus *typically* stored in the program's stack frame (though the standard leaves this choice to the 'processor', Fortran-speak for implementation). In this case the compiler apparently put i 4 'real's (probably 16 bytes) after the end of totlev, so assigning to totlev(24) actually changes i. Fortran basically requires that an integer and single/default-precision real variable be the same size, and while it *doesn't* require any particular relationship between the representations for integers and reals, most machines today use 'IEEE 754' floating-point and in that system a real 0.0 has the same representation as an integer 0.

On many though not all computer architectures it is possible to address code by indexing an array out of range, but this almost always requires indexes *far* out of range: millions or billions or more, not one or two. On older architectures it was often possible both to read and write code this way, but most systems since about 1980 have memory protection so that you can't *write* to code. In particular all Windows NT-series systems do this, which includes Windows 7.

Comment: @Peter 1. There are compiler options that you can use to aneble run-time checks. 2.Fortran has *many* array inquire functions and size() is among them. Please Read The Fortran Manual.

Comment: Of course, there is a size_of_array function, but it is spelt as `size`.  Your reference book on Fortran will tell you about it.  You would modify the do loop to by `do 100 i = 1, size(totlev)`.